# How to change a split str into a normal str

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a code that does

```
 a = "hello world"
 a.split(' ')
```

then it does other things and after that when it prints it prints like this

```
 ['hello','world']
```

how would i make it change back to printing

```
 hello word
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `' '.join(['hello','world'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a list, you can use `' '.join`:

```
s = ['hello','world']
new_s = ' '.join(s)
```

Output:

```
'hello world'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help